# Android: Improper text scaling when draw text on canvas

Tags: android

I am drawing formatted text on canvas using `DynamicLayout`, and I need to implement some sort of zooming. I tried to use `canvas.scale(...)` for it. But when text contains highlights, text is scaled inconsistent with background, like this:

[image: scaled text with highlight]

Code which draws text is very simple:

```
canvas.scale(zoom, zoom);
TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint();
textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
DynamicLayout layout = new DynamicLayout(text, textPaint, width,
                            Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 1.0f, false);
layout.draw(canvas);
```

How to make it right way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved this issue, setting `textPaint.setSubpixelText(true);`